# Error with ninja after setting Clang as its own compiler with CCMAKE

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-clang, ninja

I've been following the instructions on http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html to setup Clang using ninja.

All goes well until I set up Clang as its own compiler using `ccmake ../llvm` following the directions on the wegpage (I set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` to my recently compiled clang++ binary in `$TARGETFOLDER/clang-llvm/build/bin/clang++`).

After that, when I type `ninja`, the following error is displayed:

```
$ ccmake ../llvm/
$ ninja

[50/2561] Building C object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ConvertUTF.c.o
FAILED: /usr/bin/cc  -DGTEST_HAS_RTTI=0 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -fPIC -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-comment -fcolor-diagnostics -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Ilib/Support -I$TARGETFOLDER/clang-llvm/llvm/lib/Support -Iinclude -I$TARGETFOLDER/clang-llvm/llvm/include -MMD -MT lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ConvertUTF.c.o -MF "lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ConvertUTF.c.o.d" -o lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ConvertUTF.c.o   -c $TARGETFOLDER/clang-llvm/llvm/lib/Support/ConvertUTF.c

cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fcolor-diagnostics’

[50/2561] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CommandLine.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I've tested it already on two machines with Ubuntu 13.10 and Ubuntu 14.04 and the same error appears.

Any ideas?

Comment: @CarlNorum I think Clang *supports*  that option(it forces color diagnostics when Ninja eats up the colors).

Comment: Have you double checked that Clang++ *is* the CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER?

Comment: Yeah my comment makes no sense. Deleting.

Comment: OP: that log says /usr/bin/cc, not the clang path you mention.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed by Hongxu Chen and as mentioned in this post http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Compilation-issues-Ubuntu-14-10-td4042443.html, you need also to set CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the recently built clang (which is not mentioned in the documentation).

Clang working now with ninja.